# Android Performance implications when changing view's visibility to INVISIBLE/GONE?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-view, android-progressbar

I've been using some progressbars in my android app (Lazy loading GridViews). So when each item is loaded I set the progressbar to become INVISIBLE. I know that

INVISIBLE : This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

GONE: This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

My doubt is when I set the progressbar to INVISIBLE does it mean that the resources needed by that View are still being used in the background? (Example the progressbar animation). If I set it to GONE will there be any change in performance (I know it might be negligible). I'm curious to know it's implications on performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference would likely vary on what the view's contents and complexity are, and if there are nested views within it. While the layout information still has to be inflated into memory for the entire layout, the view measurements would not have to be calculated for a view that is GONE or its children, and it would not be drawn, whereas INVISIBLE only removes the rendering of the view (and its children) while still calculating the view measurements and its children.

If you don't want the view to appear again in the current lifetime of the activity or fragment, you can use **parent.removeView(progressView)** to remove it entirely for the best performance and memory optimization.

In your case it may not help much, but if you're going for bleeding edge optimization then I would take the approach to remove the view once it's done.